# Unix property file read using script

Tags: shell, unix

My property file:

```
a.prop  

user=abc  
location=home

user=xyz  
location=roamer
```

I need to read a.prop and keep user and location inside a variable so that I can pass them to my other script (check.sh) as an argument.

The check.sh needs to be called for all the list of user/location.

I don't want to use AWK

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a free coding site.

Comment: "some env. constraints". Could you be any more vague?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extremely fragile, ill-advised solution that invokes a function for each stanza of your config, but requires the exact format of your input and is vulnerable to many, many attack vectors.  Use (or, preferrably not) at your own risk!

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() { echo "user is $user, location is $location"; }

eval "$(sed -e '/^$/s//foo/' input; echo foo)"
```

You would be much better off pre-processing the input, and a willingness to use awk would be helpful.

Comment: Hi I am sorry but this is not fulfilling my requirement as i need to read the 1st set and then pass the values as argument to check.sh and then read the 2nd set and so  on

Comment: Change the function `foo` so that it uses your parameters as you need.  That is, have it call `check.sh` instead of merely calling `echo`.  The ability to modify code to suit your purposes is essential if you want to use a computer effectively.

Comment: But please note the warnings I initially provided.  This is *not* intended as a serious answer.  It is a tongue-in-cheek solution that would be better written as "you have demonstrated no effort to solve this problem yourself".  There are some techniques demonstrated here that may be useful, and it would certainly be instructive to understand how this works, but injecting function calls into your config file and evaluating the result is a terrible, terrible thing to actually do in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
while read -r line; do
    key=${line%%=*}          # the left-hand-side of the =
    case $key in
        user) user=${line#*=} ;;
        location) location=${line#*=} ;;
        *) continue ;;   # skip this line
    esac
    if [[ -n $user ]] && [[ -n $location ]]; then
        echo "have user=$user and location=$location" 
        check.sh "$user" "$location"
        unset user location
    fi
done < a.prop
```

This version is a little unsafer: just assume the properties are valid shell variable assignments.

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line != *=* ]] && continue
    declare "$line"
    if [[ -n $user ]] && [[ -n $location ]]; then
        echo "have user=$user and location=$location" 
        check.sh "$user" "$location"
        unset user location
    fi
done < a.prop
```

Or, assuming "user" always appears before "location"

```
grep -E '^(user|location)=' a.prop | 
  while read userline; read locline; do 
    declare "$userline"
    declare "$locline"
    echo "have user=$user and location=$location"
    check.sh "$user" "$location"
  done
```